# Products of irrational numbers

Tags: transcendental-numbers

Hello ladies and gentlemen!
A friend of mine and I have been thinking about this particular issue: under what circumstances is the product of two irrational numbers rational?

For example, multiplying $\sqrt{2}$ by any *nonzero* rational multiple of $\sqrt{2}$ or its inverse we obtain a rational number. Moreover, whenever we multiply an irrational number by a rational multiple of its inverse we obviously obtain a rational number.

I've also thought of the following case: if $q= \frac{m}{n}$ is in lowest terms where m and n are not k-th powers of integers, $\large q^{\frac{k-l}{k}} \cdot q^{\frac{l}{k}}$ is also rational.

In that direction, what is the best we know? i.e., is it known *exactly* when the product of two irrational numbers is rational? Or even, is it known *exactly* when the product of two transcendental numbers is algebraic?

I am a freshman and lessons started just one week ago so please be tolerant :)
References are welcome and appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we knew this *exactly*, the irrationality of $e\pi $ and the like would not be open problems.

Comment: We know very little about the numbers you wrote.

Comment: You've already given the complete answer: "whenever we multiply an irrational number by a rational multiple of its inverse we obviously obtain a rational number."

Comment: You say *nonzero* rational multiple of $\sqrt2$ but zero is a perfectly good rational number.

Comment: @DanielRust the zero multiple of $\sqrt{2}$ is not irrational!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Right, I don't know how I failed to notice that it was actually a perfect answer xD

Comment: @StevePap I think it's better to consider, for some chosen irrational $p$, all real numbers (not just irrational) $q$ such that $qp$ is rational. The reason this is better is because, if we call the above set $R_p$, then $R_p$ forms an abelian group under addition (with identity being zero). Of course, it's rather easy to see that $R_p$ has only one rational element which is zero (if we extend to all real $p$, then every element of $R_p$ is rational).

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is any rational number, and $b$ is any irrational number, then $c=a/b$ is irrational (it's pretty easy to prove that; I can give specifics if necessary) so the product of the two irrational numbers $b$ and $c$ is rational.  And **every** case of a product of two irrational numbers being rational is an instance of exactly that situation, as you'll see if you think it through.

Comment: 'product of the two irrational numbers is rational' really? How about $(\sqrt 3-\sqrt 2)\cdot \sqrt 2$?

Comment: @mathlove : You're really not paying attention very well at all.  I didn't say that you get a rational number in EVERY case in which you multiply two irrational numbers.  Rather, I wrote about what happens in cases in which you do get a rational number.

Comment: I understand what you mean. hmm, maybe typo? $b$ and $c$ instead of $a$ and $c$?

Comment: You must mean the product of the irrationals $b$ and $c$ is rational. And I assume the intention was $a \neq 0$.  The whole argument seems a tautology though.

Comment: It's really a tautology as Macavity pointed out. I was asking for something more concrete, which as HagenvonEitzen pointed out in the comments, I had already mentioned in the question xD

Comment: Typo fixed: The product of the two irrational numbers $b$ and $c$ is rational.

Comment: That it's a "tautology" was the point of my sentence beginning with "And every[...]".